# Python - syntax error in established code

Tags: python, command-line

So, I'm trying to get nifscripts to work with blender 2.49b on a Mac. I suspect there may be an issue with the installed versions of python, but for the life of me I can't suss it out.

So, when I start blender from the command line, I see:

```
Compiled with Python version 2.5.6.
Checking for installed Python... got it!
```

So far so good. Running a system report generates expected output:

```
Paths:

/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python25.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/.blender/scripts
/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/.blender/scripts/bpymodules
```

So, it seems to be using the same python it was built off of. However, when I try to run the `nif_common.py` script, I start getting syntax errors. The first one seemed to involve the `with... as f` keyword, which I resolved by using the more traditional `f =` syntax.

However, now I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nif_common.py", line 91, in <module>
  File "/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/.blender/scripts/bpymodules/pyffi/formats/nif/__init__.py", line 3277
    return b''
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I fail to see the invalid syntax; this scripts uses that form several times, and only the last does it throw an error.

Line 91 of `nif_common.py` reads:

```
from pyffi.formats.nif import NifFormat
```

And the `__init__.py` file contains at line 3277:

```
    def _get_string(self, offset):
        """A wrapper around string_palette.palette.get_string. Used by get_node_name
        etc. Returns the string at given offset."""
        if offset == -1:
            return b''

        if not self.string_palette:
            return b''</pre>
```

Now, my familiarity with python is minimal, so I'm not sure whether the offending `''` does anything or not. But I can't see how invalid syntax would end up in established code like this...

Comment: I am lead admin for Niftools. It is best to drop by http://www.niftools.org/chat.html
You are bound to run into more issues, we can help you better there. As these scripts are written 2.49b the expectation here is not to get support, @Ideasman42 tends to just be awesome anyways.

Answer (score 4):

`b''` or `b""` define a byte string, this is a feature of **Python2.7** or **3.x**

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707085/python-string-b-prefix-byte-literals

You can use Python2.7 with Blender2.4x, but you'll have to recompile Blender, linking to the newer Python version.

Answer (score 0):

As ideasman has explained you need at least 2.6.x of python installed, due to the *relatively* newer python features uses compared to the version you have currently install, the recommended version being 2.6.7

The script have additional dependencies, pyffi which requires the use of the 32-bit install.

For recommended installation requirements see - http://niftools.sourceforge.net/wiki/Blender